# How does an instance of the AmazonEc2Client deal with network interruptions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

We are using the AWS SDK to interact with AWS. For example, to create, stop and restart ec2 instances. The first step if to instantiate the client and then it can be used but I believe if the network connection fails after the client is instantiated, that instance can no longer be used. However, it might be the instance is in the process of connecting to AWS again after the connection is re-enabled and this process takes several seconds. So I am wondering if anyone can describe the expected behavior of this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the AWS SDKs will automatically retry commands in cases of network distruptions or command throttling. However, in cases where the SDKs still cannot perform their action, they will fail and return an error code back to you. The error code returned depends on the actual failure that happened. So you need to handle the possibility of errors.

Use this to reference the various error codes that the SDKs can return:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html

> I believe if the network connection fails after the client is instantiated, that instance can no longer be used.

Incorrect. If a connection fails, the command will return an error code, but you can retry the command (or issue a different command) with the same client.

> However, it might be the instance is in the process of connecting to AWS again after the connection

The SDK clients don't keep persist connections to AWS around. When you call a function on the SDK, only then does it connect to AWS to perform the action requested.

Comment: Thanks. Did look at documentation -- would be useful if this comment about connecting only to perform the action was there. If you have a link that would be great.

Comment: No docs, but you can look at the source code of the various SDKs on GitHub to see the behaviour: https://github.com/aws/